# Using heredoc to a character device in bash script. EOF error

Tags: shell-script, here-document

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=enp4s0

mac_address=$(ip link show $interface | grep ether | awk '{print $2}')


cat > /dev/usb/lp0 <<EOF
SIZE 30 mm,90 mm,CLS,TEXT 200,40,0,90,2,2,"MAC Address of $interface:",TEXT 140,40,0,90,2,2,"$mac_address",PRINT 1,END
>EOF
```

I am using TSPL language to print to the character device. The problem is that content to be printed has to be in double quotes. So for example `TEXT 200,40,0,90,2,2,"Some text to be printed"`. I also want to embed a variable inside the text.

`echo "SIZE 30 mm,90 mm,CLS,TEXT 200,40,0,90,2,2,"MAC Address of $interface:",TEXT 140,40,0,90,2,2,"$mac_address",PRINT 1,END > /dev/usb/lp0` is not working because the double quote nesting is breaking the commands of TSPL.

The error I am getting with heredoc is

```
warning:here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Comment: why do you have `>EOF` and not just `EOF` to close the heredoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thrig suggests, changing `>EOF` to `EOF` makes quick work of your issue:

```bash
cat > /dev/usb/lp0 <<EOF
SIZE 30 mm,90 mm,CLS,TEXT 200,40,0,90,2,2,"MAC Address of $interface:",TEXT 140,40,0,90,2,2,"$mac_address",PRINT 1,END
EOF
```

I recommend writing bash scripts in an IDE with good syntax highlighting in the future, VS Code quickly made note of this discrepancy. Cheers!

Comment: VS Code does bash syntax highlighting? What extention?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is just part of the base software, whenever you open a shell file the file type in the bottom right (by character encoding and line ending) should say "Shell Script" as the autodetected file type, and appropriate highlighting should be applied